# What does multiplying two permutations do to their order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

when multiplying different permutations together, I noticed that the product will always be of the same order.

Let's suppose these two permutations:

σ₁ = (12)(3) and σ₂ = (132)

That means that σ2σ1 = (32)(1), and σ1σ2 = (13)(2).

Obviously, these products are two different permutations. Yet, they are of the same order and this seems to be true for all products of permutations.

Is there a general rule for the order of a product of two permutations or does anyone have an explanation about what's going on here?

Comment: If $a, b$ are elements of a group $G$, then the order of $ab$ is equal to the order of $ba$, since if $(ab)^n = 1$, then $(ba)^n = a^{-1} a (ba)^n = a^{-1} (ab)^n a = 1$.

Comment: It's a well-known result that the order of a product of disjoint permutations is the least common multiple of the orders of the terms.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks! Is it mathematically correct to just leave it as it is or is there a way to get rid of the two permutations a and a^-1 left and right of the last term?

Comment: @ChrisEckhert: sorry, I don’t understand the question. Is the argument convincing or not? Try it with $n=2$: suppose that $abab = 1$, then $baba = a^{-1} ababa = a^{-1}(abab)a = a^{-1} (1) a = a^{-1} a = 1$.

Comment: @Joppy Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your permutation $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint cycles $\sigma_1, \dots,\sigma_n$, then the order of the product $\operatorname{ord}(\sigma)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord(\sigma_1),\dots,\operatorname{ord}(\sigma_n)})$, where $\operatorname{lcm}$ is the lowest common multiple.

Comment: But $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are not disjoint.  So how does your answer relate to this question?